# Render and activate filters from code [React/Searchkit]

Tags: reactjs, searchkit

How can I assign an existing value to a filter which It has been already rendered in react?

Comment: try setstate() method

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which filter component you're using. Most of SearchKit components support render props like `listComponent` and `itemComponent`. There, you can pass a custom React component that receives variables and callbacks from the specific SearchKit component as properties.

Here a quick example of the `MenuFilter`:

```
<MenuFilter
  field="languages.raw"
  title="Languages"
  id="languages"
  listComponent={({items, toggleItem}) => {
    // Logic would be here ....
  }}
/>
```

Could you give extra details of what filter component you're using and what kind of field/value it is handling? In that way, we can provide you helpful answers.

Comment: I am using structure like that:
               estructuraNew = <RefinementListFilter 
id={id_filtro} 
key={id_filtro} 
title={titulo_filtro} 
field={field_filtro} 
operator={operator} 
size={size_filtro} 
listComponent={ItemHistogramList} 
showCount={showCount} 
showMore={showMore} 
containerComponent={<Panel collapsable={collapsable} defaultCollapsed={defaultCollapsed}/>}/>